# How to Get Specific Variables from One Class to Another?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables

I am currently in the processing of self making an inventory system, and am trying to better organize my code in specific classes and methods. Currently, I am trying to organize a class that does user input, sends that input to another class to use.

Here is my relevant code:

```py
class user_interaction(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = self.ask()
        self.options = self.ask_options()
        self.add_item_num = None
        self.add_item_price = None
        self.add_item_quant = None
        self.add_item_name = None

    def ask(self):
        while 1:
            name = input("What is your name?\n")
            if name == "":
                print("Ha! You have to enter a name!")
            else:
                print("Welcome to the Shepherdstown Bake Shop " + name)
                return name
            
        
                
    def ask_options(self):
        while 1:
            option = input('''What would you like to do? \n1. Add a Item: \n2. Delete a Item:\n3. Edit an Item: \n4. View Inventory \n5. End Program\n''')
            if option == '1':       
                print("Welcome to the adding process " + self.name)
                ????
                break

     def enter_data(message, typ):
            while True:
                try:
                    v = typ(input(message))
                except ValueError:
                    print(f"Thats not an {typ}!")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            return v

   def add_item_interaction(self):
            self.add_item_num = enter_data("What is the items #?\n", int)
            self.add_item_price = enter_data("What is the items price?\n", float)
            self.add_item_quant = enter_data("What is the items quantity?\n", int)

            while True:
                self.add_name = enter_data("What is the items name?\n", str)
                if name == "":
                    print("Ha! You have to enter a name!")
                    continue
                break
```

and my other class

```
class DataBase_Management(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = []


    def make_dict_items(self):
        with open("Items2.csv") as fp:
            reader = csv.reader(fp)
            labels = next(reader, None)
            result = []
            for row in reader:
                if row:
                    row[0] = int(row[0])
                    row[1] = float(row[1])
                    row[2] = int(row[2])
                    pairs = zip(labels, row)
                    self.result.append(dict(pairs))
    
    def add_item(self):
        #Make Entries the variables in new_row???
        new_row = [item_num, price, quant, name]
        with open("Items2.csv", "a+") as  fp:
           reader = csv.reader(fp)
           fp.seek(0)
           labels = next(reader, None)
           writer = csv.writer(fp)
           new_record = dict(zip(labels, new_row))
           self.result.append(new_record)
           writer.writerow(new_record.values())
           print("Item Added! Check Inventory Again to see!")
```

How would I make it so the entries gotten in class `User_interaction`, in the method `add_item_interaction`, are sent to the `add_item` method in the `DataBase_Management` class? For example, I am trying to make it where `self.add_item_num = item_num` in the `add_item` method in the database management class?

Comment: How do you currently use these classes? You don't show that. It sounds like the `User_interaction` class needs an instance of the `DataBase_Management` class.

Comment: `User_Interaction` has a main loop, which calls various methods and performs them. For example, if a user inputs 3 for their option (code for that not shown), the user is directed to the entries to add input, and then I would like their input to be sent to `Database Management`, the method `add_item` to be added. Wouldn't it be the other way around, that DataBase_Management needs an instance of User_interaction?

Comment: But it sounds like the `User_Interaction` class knows exactly *when* to call `add_item`, so it should have an instance of `Database Management` to hand.

Comment: I am confused on how to do this, In a sense, what you are talking about would make the variables in `add_item` equal the input variables I have in `add_item_interaction`? How would I make it so in my loop, when a user enters 1, it calls the input functions in the first class, and then sends it to add_item?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you want `add_item` to be: `def add_item(self, item_num, price, quant, name):` and `add_item_interaction` should call: `database.add_item(item_num, price, quant, name)`

Comment: How does that work? The entries in the first class, need to go to the add_item method in the second class so they can become a new row, and be added to the database. Is that what you just suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the `User_Interaction` class should have its own `Database_Management` instance and use it when necessary:

```py
class User_Interaction:

    def __init__(self):
        self.database = DataBase_Management()
        ...

   def add_item_interaction(self):
            add_item_num = self.enter_data("What is the items #?\n", int)
            add_item_price = self.enter_data("What is the items price?\n", float)
            add_item_quant = self.enter_data("What is the items quantity?\n", int)

            while True:
                add_name = self.enter_data("What is the items name?\n", str)
                if add_name == "":
                    print("Ha! You have to enter a name!")
                    continue
                break
            self.database.add_item(add_item_num, add_item_price, add_item_quant, add_name)
    ...

class DataBase_Management:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = []

    
    def add_item(self, item_num, price, quant, name):
        ...
```

Comment: Ahhh okay that makes a lot of sense. Thank you. Would it be too much for you to show me how to run this in my loop that I added? If a user inputs 1 into my loop, it should send them to enter inputs for the items, and then add the items in the database. How would I do that? Something like items = DataBase_Management()
                items.make_dict_items()
                add_item_interaction()
                items.add_item()                                                                                                                  In the ask_options method for if input == "1"?

Comment: That's another question. You should start a new question all about that. However, you should look up some tutorials on using classes since you have made some classic mistakes.