# How to Call/Run Specific Methods within my Main Loop?

Tags: python, loops, class, oop, methods

I am currently in the process of making an inventory system, and am working on my main loop. Currently I am trying to make it in the main loop, that when a user inputs 1, it sends them through the process of adding a new item.

I have the following relevant code:

```
import csv
class user_interaction(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = self.ask()
        self.options = self.ask_options()
        self.database = DataBase_Management()
        
    def ask(self):
        while True:
            name = input("What is your name?\n")
            if name == "":
                print("Ha! You have to enter a name!")
            else:
                print("Welcome to the Shepherdstown Bake Shop " + name)
                return name
            
        
                
    def ask_options(self):
        while True:
            option = input('''What would you like to do? \n1. Add a Item: \n2. Delete a Item:\n3. Edit an Item: \n4. View Inventory \n5. End Program\n''')
            if option == '1':       
                print("Welcome to the adding process " + self.name)
                items = DataBase_Management()
                items.make_dict_items()
                self.add_item_interaction()
                #add_item_interaction()
                #items.add_item()
                break

   def enter_data(selfmessage, typ):
            while True:
                try:
                    v = typ(input(message))
                except ValueError:
                    print(f"Thats not an {typ}!")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            return v

     def add_item_interaction(self):
            add_item_num = enter_data("What is the items #?\n", int)
            add_item_price = enter_data("What is the items price?\n", float)
            add_item_quant = enter_data("What is the items quantity?\n", int)

            while True:
                add_name = self.enter_data("What is the items name?\n", str)
                if name == "":
                    print("Ha! You have to enter a name!")
                    continue
                break
            self.database.add_item(add_item_num, add_item_price, add_item_quant, add_name)
```

as well as the other class:

```
class DataBase_Management(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = []


    def make_dict_items(self):
        with open("Items2.csv") as fp:
            reader = csv.reader(fp)
            labels = next(reader, None)
            result = []
            for row in reader:
                if row:
                    row[0] = int(row[0])
                    row[1] = float(row[1])
                    row[2] = int(row[2])
                    pairs = zip(labels, row)
                    self.result.append(dict(pairs))


    def add_item(self, item_num, price, quant, name):
        new_row = [item_num, price, quant, name]
        with open("Items2.csv", "a+") as  fp:
           reader = csv.reader(fp)
           fp.seek(0)
           labels = next(reader, None)
           writer = csv.writer(fp)
           new_record = dict(zip(labels, new_row))
           self.result.append(new_record)
           writer.writerow(new_record.values())
           print("Item Added! Check Inventory Again to see!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = user_interaction() 
    while True:
        obj.ask_options()
```

I was wondering how I can implement it into my `ask_options` main loop, that if a user inputs 1, it sends them to `add_item_interaction` and `enter_data` in the first class, and then adds the new  items to the database as is done by `add_item` in the second class? The comments in the `ask_options` method were my attempts/thoughts at doing so.

EDIT: Added some suggested code, and seem to now get error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
 line 209, in <module>
    obj = user_interaction()
  
line 7, in __init__
    self.options = self.ask_options()
  
 
line 28, in ask_options
    self.add_item_interaction()

AttributeError: 'user_interaction' object has no attribute 'add_item_interaction'
```

Comment: `while True:` is more pythonic than `while 1:`

Comment: IIUC, all you need to do is to call your `add_item_interaction` method, i.e., after `print("Welcome to the adding process " + self.name)`, do `self.add_item_interaction()`. (Next you will most likely get an error `enter_data is not defined` since you call `enter_data()` instead of `self.enter_data()` in `add_item_interaction`.)

Comment: Ok, I see you have asked a new question which is the right thing to do on stackoverflow. However, you are just using this site as your personal software development environment. You should at least be trying something yourself, finding a problem and asking about that problem. (So, something like what fsimonjetz said).

Comment: @fsimonjetz, If I do that I get, AttributeError: 'user_interaction' object has no attribute 'add_item_interaction'. Also, I believe I need to  make sure i Include `items = DataBase_Management()` and `items.make_dict_items()` before it to make the list of dictionaries, before I attempt to add to it

Comment: @quamrana I understand that, and tried to implement a solution that didn't work. I am going to have to implement something similiar for several other methods, and figured once I figured this out, I could try to attempt it again for the other methods on my own

Comment: Ok, if you have tried something that didn't work, you should publish that here and specify the exact reasons why. It looks like you almost did that in your reply to fsimonjetz.

Comment: @quamrana i understand, I apologize. Any clue on how I would fix this? I know I must be close

Comment: Basically you should update the question with the code you used in your comment along with the full error traceback.

Comment: @py_coder1019 well, I can't reproduce your error. I tried it and it's turning out exactly as I assumed, the `add_item_interaction` starting to do its thing until the `enter_data` method is (not) called, and then it's called with the wrong number of arguments. It's really not a good idea to make things that complex before you're sure they work as expected, the way things are now you bit off more than you can chew. I'm voting to close this for the reason of "needs more focus".

Comment: @fsimonjetz: (fyi see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73764113/4834) to the previous question)

Comment: @quamrana I see, now it makes sense why there is `self.database` in the `user_interaction` while at the same time OP doesn't seem to be aware it's accessible in the methods.

Comment: I see you edited your `ask_options()` method, but you won't get the error you claim. (You should get a `TypeError` on `items.make_dict_items()`)

Comment: @fsimonjetz I agree I probably went over my head with what I currently have, before testing to see if any of it worked. I had it working where I could add items, but it was all handled by a single class before, and am now experimenting with having dedicated classes for specific tasks. I added `self.add_items_interaction() to the `if option == "1"` section, as well as adding `self.enter_data` to the `add_item_interaction(self) method.

Comment: @quamrana I dont though. I still seem to get AttributeError: 'user_interaction' object has no attribute 'add_item_interaction'.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback,

Comment: @quamrana done, I apologize for the confusion/slowness on my part

Comment: Ok, so your edit shows a traceback which has: `self.add_item_interaction()`, but that doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @quamrana It was present in the code posted, just forgot to add the parenthesis to it. It appears in the `ask_options` in the first class in `if option =- '1'`. Still get that error though.

Comment: The code posted is not what you are using.  Give me a while and I'll write an answer.

Comment: @quamrana Let me remformat everything to what I currently have. I really do appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should be the next step forward:

```py
import csv
class User_Interaction:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.database = DataBase_Management()
        self.database.make_dict_items()
    
    @staticmethod
    def ask():
        while True:
            name = input("What is your name?\n")
            if name == "":
                print("Ha! You have to enter a name!")
            else:
                print("Welcome to the Shepherdstown Bake Shop " + name)
                return name
                
    def ask_options(self):
        option = input('''What would you like to do? \n1. Add a Item: \n2. Delete a Item:\n3. Edit an Item: \n4. View Inventory \n5. End Program\n''')
        if option == '1':       
            print("Welcome to the adding process " + self.name)
            self.add_item_interaction()
        elif option == '2':
            ...

    @staticmethod
    def enter_data(message, typ):
            while True:
                try:
                    v = typ(input(message))
                except ValueError:
                    print(f"Thats not an {typ}!")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            return v

     def add_item_interaction(self):
            add_item_num = self.enter_data("What is the items #?\n", int)
            add_item_price = self.enter_data("What is the items price?\n", float)
            add_item_quant = self.enter_data("What is the items quantity?\n", int)

            while True:
                add_name = self.enter_data("What is the items name?\n", str)
                if add_name == "":
                    print("Ha! You have to enter a name!")
                    continue
                break
            self.database.add_item(add_item_num, add_item_price, add_item_quant, add_name)
```

Note the changes to the `__init__()` method and how some other methods are marked `@staticmethod` since those never need access to `self`.

Also `ask_options()` doesn't need its own `while` loop since that is already included below.

Also I've added an `elif/...` in `ask_options()` as a placeholder for all the other options that need implementing and is not real code.

```py
class DataBase_Management:
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = []

    def make_dict_items(self):
        with open("Items2.csv") as fp:
            reader = csv.reader(fp)
            labels = next(reader, None)
            result = []
            for row in reader:
                if row:
                    row[0] = int(row[0])
                    row[1] = float(row[1])
                    row[2] = int(row[2])
                    pairs = zip(labels, row)
                    self.result.append(dict(pairs))

    def add_item(self, item_num, price, quant, name):
        new_row = [item_num, price, quant, name]
        with open("Items2.csv", "a+") as  fp:
           reader = csv.reader(fp)
           fp.seek(0)
           labels = next(reader, None)
           writer = csv.writer(fp)
           new_record = dict(zip(labels, new_row))
           self.result.append(new_record)
           writer.writerow(new_record.values())
           print("Item Added! Check Inventory Again to see!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = User_Interaction.ask()
    obj = User_Interaction(name) 
    while True:
        obj.ask_options()
```

Note that some variables can just be local to methods and don't need to be members. (eg. You don't need `self.add_item_name`)

Note that the `__init__()` method only really initialises members that it needs control over. (Yes, it is debateable whether `ask()` should be called outside as I have done or whether it should be called inside as you did)

Note that there are some formatting issues with your posted code. You should be using an IDE that would immediately highlight such things so that we never see them in code posted here.

Note that classes can be declared: `class Foo:` (No brackets nor the need to derive from `object`)

Also note that, as I've said previously, you should not use stackoverflow and your personal software development environment. You are asking questions and stitching together a program from the answers in a [cargo cult style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) that will lead to much confusion and less than optimal learning.